# Sumifs unique values in range only with multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I've been struggling with this for a while now.

In sheet 1, I have two columns:

```
Column A:
Dates
23/02/2017
03/08/2017
22/02/2018
22/02/2018
02/08/2018

Column B:
Final
Interim
Final
Interim
Final
```

In sheet 2, I have a table with dates going across (e.g. row 5 has the first day of a month and row 6 the end day of a month) and company names going down:

```
Column C:
Company A
Company B
Company C

Column D (row 5): 
  1-Feb-17 (as a number) 

Column D (row 6): 
  28-Feb-17 (as a number)
```

I need a formula that I can copy into cell D7 of sheet that (I can copy across and down) that will return the date that falls between the start and end date and subject to the values in column B being either Final or Interim (there are other values this column takes).

I have used sumifs but it sums dates when they are non-unique. I also cannot manipulate it to work as an OR function i.e. so what I essentially need is a sumifs unique dates within range if type is final OR interim.

I've tried to elucidate this issue as best as possible but appreciate it might be difficult to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of the date that you think should appear in D7?

Comment: 23/02/2017. And if I was to edit the dates in rows 5 and 6 to say 01/02/2018 and 28/02/2018 then 22/02/2018. My current sumifs construction sums the two 22/02/2018s and cannot work for multiple criteria e.g. final or interim - only one.